# Find file with highest (purely numerical) filename

Tags: zsh

Given a directory, which among its entries has at least one with the following properties:

- It is a directory file
- It's name consists only of digits

My goal is to find of all these directories the one with the numerically highest value.

Using zsh, I arrived at the following solution:

```
if cd $MYDIR
then
  all_dirs=(<->(N/))
  all_dirs_sorted=(${(On)all_dirs})
  highest_dir=${all_dirs_sorted[1]}
  cd -
fi
```

This works, but I wonder whether I can write this simpler (for instance without using the temporary variables `all_dirs` and/or `all_dirs_sorted`.

Comment: Are you open to using Linux utilities instead of zsh? If so, `ls | sort -nr | head -n 1` would do the trick. Note that `-n` sorts [numerically](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html) and `r` displays the largest numerical value.

Comment: This would not work if you have also files which are NOT purely numerical, and it would give possible nonsense results if you have a filename with an embedded newlines. Not that I would create files with such a name, but this is a directory where many different process are creating files and I want to be on the safe side.